# What did John Chrysostom mean by "evil intreated"?

Tags: meaning, john-chrysostom

The following line from [an old translation of John Chrysostom's *Homily 14 on Romans*](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/210214.htm) is rather perplexing:

> It [creation] **was evil intreated** for your sake, and became
> corruptible; yet it has had no wrong done it.

What is meant by "was evil intreated"? I can't find any definitions of "intreat" or "entreat" that would fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lexico suggests [*entreat*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/entreat) for *intreat* and has

> entreat²
>
> *archaic [with object and adverbial]* Treat (someone) in a specified manner
>
> > ‘the King, I fear, hath ill entreated her’

which seems to fit admirably: "Creation was treated evilly."

(Lexico's example sentence is a quote from Christopher Marlowe's *Edward the Second,* which shows just how archaic it is.)